# Polynomial time separation and optimization for an LP with exponential columns and rows?

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, computational-complexity

We know the fundamental theorem on the equivalence of separation and optimization: an optimization problem can be solved in a  polynomial time if and only if there is a polynomial time separation oracle.

Let us consider a special case: We have an LP with exponential numbers of columns and rows.
If we have a polynomial time oracle to generate columns (vars) and rows (constraints), can we solve this LP in a polynomial time?

I know that the fundamental theorem is proved using the ellipsoid algorithm. If the LP only has an exponential number of rows, we can apply the theorem for the primal problem; If the LP only has an exponential number of columns, we can apply the theorem for the dual problem.
Does the ellipsoid algorithm still work for primal and dual problems simultaneously? Perhaps, one needs to define the `polynomial time' to a proper problem data.

Comment: Yes, "polynomial time" means time polynomial in the size of the problem data.  For example, you'll have an "L" in theoretical complexity analysis for interior point methods for LP.